# SQL Server split string and get the value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi all please help me the

Get result from

```
select details from table
enter code here
```

Result :

```
Title|Firstname|Lastname|Mobilephone~Mr|jack|steve|123456789~Mr|test|Ltest|123456789~Mrs|Demo|Ldemo|12345678~Mrs|Fname|Lname|1234567
```

i need the below result

```
Title    FirstName    LastName    Mobile
Mr       jack        steve        1234567789 
etc...
```

Comment: i´d consider refactornig the table design instead working around it..

Comment: I will go with Kevin Esche, you should think about refactoring the table design,however i have given solution to your question in below. please check below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write stored procedure which will scan the complete line and give you pipe separated values in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

One of solution to your problem is as given below :

```
DECLARE @PARAM_STRING VARCHAR(1000)=REPLACE('Title|Firstname|Lastname|Mobilephone~Mr|jack|steve|123456789~Mr|test|Ltest|123456789~Mrs|Demo|Ldemo|12345678~Mrs|Fname|Lname|1234567','|',''',''')+''''
DECLARE @DYNAMIC_QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT,DATA VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @TABLE 
SELECT 1 ID, 'SELECT '+DATA FROM (
SELECT A.B.value('.','VARCHAR(50)')DATA FROM 
(SELECT CAST('<A>'''+REPLACE(@PARAM_STRING,'~','''</A><A>''')+'</A>' AS     XML)COL)T
CROSS APPLY T.COL.nodes('/A') AS A(B))F WHERE DATA<>''
SELECT  @DYNAMIC_QUERY=STUFF((SELECT ' UNION ALL ' + CAST(DATA AS     VARCHAR(MAX))     [text()]FROM @TABLE WHERE ID = t.ID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,10,' ')
FROM @TABLE t GROUP BY ID
EXECUTE(@DYNAMIC_QUERY)
```